# Loading new page after button is clicked (not duplicate)

Tags: javascript, html, django, xmlhttprequest

I am developing a web application (for learning purposes) and I am stuck at **how to load another page after a particular button is clicked**

I am using django 1.4.5 web framework along with python 2.7.4 
I have already designed all the html pages and javascript and css files.

I have no idea about HttpRequests. And studying various tutorials i came across these three methods.

1)

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","screen2/",false);
xhr.send(null);
```

2)

```
location.href="/screen2/"
```

3)

```
window.open("/screen2/","_parent");
```

all of 'em are kept inside the function `setup()`,the button's `onclick` is set to `onclick="setup()"`

Yes, I comment them out to keep only one of them "alive" at a time.

django urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^screen1/$',screen1),
    url(r'^screen2/$',screen2),
)
```

django views.py file

```
def screen1(request):
    f = open(r"mysite/frontend/1st screen.html",'r')
    html = f.read()
    return HttpResponse(html)

def screen2(request):
    f = open(r'mysite/frontend/2nd Screen.html','r')
    html = f.read()
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

**Second and third methods work the first doesn't.** I don't understand why.

**Also, How to send the corresponding scripts and css files with the request ?**

Answer (score 1):

The first is making an ajax request, using javacript.  The response is contained in javascript.  The other 2 are changing the location (url) of the webpage.

Additionally: Django provides a fully contained templating engine, and template loader that wraps all the loading of templates for you.  You should not have to manually open the file and read its contents and return it as a string like you are doing below:

```
def screen2(request):
    f = open(r'mysite/frontend/2nd Screen.html','r')
    html = f.read()
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

The django [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/) provides an exapmle of how to render templates using djangos built in functions

I am Assuming that you have not done any configuration to serve static files (How to send the corresponding scripts and css files with the request ?). Django provides examples of how to do this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

Comment: Got the ajax part. 
No I am not using templates for the moment. 

I thought you had answered the part of sending the css and js files well, and I had accepted the answer, but having read the example a 50 times, I dont find it clear enough for someone new like me and am not able to tackle the problem yet. Please, if you may, re-explain.